# More than one instance of any JBOSS Product with oracle not working

Tags: oracle, jboss, drools-guvnor, gatein

I am using jboss products like GateIn, JBPM, Drools Guvnor...etc. By default all of those products provide HSQL DB database. I migrated the HSQLDB database to Oracle db. Here what is the problem is when i create two instance of any product (eg: GateIn) in two machines and connect its JCR/IDM tables with same oracle by creating two user instance only one GateIn will become works fine and the other one shows some database errors of JCR and IDM tables

Is oracle shares anything common in the case of JCR and IDM tables creation other than tables?

I got same issue in the case of JBPM, Drools Guvnor too. I am running those products in JBoss server

Answer (score 0):

For GateIn you must add the property "gatein.idm.datasource.schema" in the configuration.properties file, with the name of the schema. For example gatein.idm.datasource.schema=MYSCHEMA1